# Cache larger-than-memory dataframe to local disk with Dask

Tags: amazon-s3, dask, dask-dataframe

I have a bunch of files in S3 which comprise a larger-than-memory dataframe.

Currently, I use Dask to read the files into a dataframe, perform an inner-join with a smaller dataset (which will change on each call to this function, whereas `huge_df` is basically the full dataset & does not change), call compute to get a much smaller pandas dataframe, and then do some processing. E.g:

```
huge_df = ddf.read_csv("s3://folder/**/*.part") 
merged_df = huge_df.join(small_df, how='inner', ...)
merged_df = merged_df.compute()
...other processing...
```

Most of the time is spent downloading the files from S3. My question is: is there a way to use Dask to cache the files from S3 on disk, so that on subsequent calls to this code, I could just read the dataframe files from disk, rather than from S3? I figure I can't just call `huge_df.to_csv(./local-dir/)` since that will bring `huge_df` into memory which won't work.

I'm sure there is a way to do this using a combination of other tools plus standard Python IO utilities, but I wanted to see if there was a way to use Dask to download the file contents from S3 and store them on the local disk without bringing everything into memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing `huge_df.to_csv` would have worked, because it would write each partition to a separate file locally, and so the whole thing would not have been in memory at once.

However, to answer the specific question, dask uses `fsspec` to manage file operations, and it allows for [local caching](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features.html#caching-files-locally), e.g., you could do

```
huge_df = ddf.read_csv("simplecache::s3://folder/**/*.part")
```

By default, this will store the files in a temporary folder, which gets cleaned up when you exit the python session, but you can provide options using an optional argument `storage_options={"simplecache": {..}}` to specify the cache location, or use "filecache" instead of "simplecache" if you want to enable the local copies to expire after some time or to check the target for updated versions.

Note that, obviously, these will only work with a distributed cluster only if all the workers have access to the same cache location, since the loading of a partition might happen on any of your workers.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I want -- except when I try `ddf.read_csv("filecache::s3//folder/subfolder/**/*.part")` I see: `ValueError: Protocol not known: filecache::s3`. It looks exactly like the suggested usage in the docs. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need the very latest fsspec, maybe the current master.